# "The book fell open"

Tags: secondary-predicates, predicative-complement

What is meaning of the sentence :     The book fell open at a page of illustrations.

The sentence doesn’t have subject ( it is passive ) for example somebody has opened the book and the book is open now so speaker describe present situation of the book and he or she uses of   fell open  instead of   has been fallen open.
In my understanding of English the sentence must be passive why it isn’t  and  whats meaning (concept) of the sentence  ?
Ehsan

Comment: The sentence has a subject: the book. And this is not a passive construction: the book is doing the action.

Comment: "Has been fallen open" is a passive **construction,** but as *fall* is intransitive it can't be passivised like that and it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence does have a subject; it is "the book". If you hold a book by the spine, and let go of the ends of the pages, the book will "fall open". When it falls open, it seems to randomly choose a page to reveal.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is *The book*.

The verb is *fall*.

*open* is a **subject predicative complement**: that is, a word or phrase which describes or identifies the subject. You see this such complements with most verbs of motion; usually they're preposition phrases or other expressions which designate the origin, path, goal or final position of the subject:

> The book fell **from his hands**.
>   The book fell **through the air**.
>   The book fell **on the floor**.
>   The book fell **down**.

But sometimes you'll find predicative complements which describe the final **state** which the action of the verb brings about in the subject.

> The door slammed **shut**.
>   The book fell **shut**.
>   The book fell **open**.

Note that with transitive there are also **object predicative complements** which describe or identify the object of the verb:

> He dropped the book **from his hands**.
>   He dropped the book **through the air**.
>   He dropped the book **on the floor**.
>   He dropped the book **down**.
>
> He slammed the door **shut**.
>   He closed the book **shut**.
>   He turned the book **open**.

Answer (score 0):

"to fall open" is a phrasal verb.

When something (usually a book) *falls open*, it doesn't necessarily mean that the book falls from a height and lands on the floor in an 'open' state. It usually means that the book in question has been used many times - it may be in a library - and many different readers have opened it at a particular page of interest.

This frequently happens with library books when the author is known for a particularly famous quote. Readers go to the shelves, find the page. Open the book (thus weakening the binding at that point), read and replace the book.

So when you take such a book to read it, it may open itself (fall open) at that particular page.